# Can I show PayPal frame to show payment reports for my users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reporting, paypal

I have task to provide my users with financial reports.

My application is sharing profit with users for using special advertisement.

PayPal report page should actually be a PayPal site frame inserted into our site - which is the actual Paypal reporting system OF OUR PAYPAL ACCOUNT that shows the transfers for that specific user.

Is it possible to do ? As I know PayPal is blocking frames or I'm wrong ?


If it is impossible I should provide some role to user when user sign up on my site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All PayPal URLs will break out of iframes. The X-FRAME header is set to SAMEORIGIN on all their sites. Do a search [here](http://web-sniffer.net/) and you'll see that:

```
HTTP Response Header

Name    Value   Delim
Status: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date:   Wed, 25 Jul 2012 13:16:27 GMT   
Server: Apache  
X-Frame-Options:    SAMEORIGIN  
Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGb [..]
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Sat, 23-Jul-2022 [...]
Location:   https://www.paypal.com/ 
Vary:   Accept-Encoding 
Content-Encoding:   gzip    
Connection: close   
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked 
Content-Type:   text/html
```

You cannot (and should not try to) [get around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options).

Comment: You can't solve the frame issue. Tell your customers to go to paypal.com and log in there. If you have a question about setting up user accounts within PayPal etc, it would probably be better to open a separate question at  http://webapps.stackexchange.com